# How to block an IP if it touches a specific file

Tags: apache, nginx, ip

I have a wordpress site and I'm constantly getting alot of spam even though I'm using disqus. What's a good way to log all the IP's which access `wp-comments-post.php` and block them permanently (or immediately block w/o logging)? Deleting/Renaming the file can be a solution but i'd like to block them so they won't come back. I'm using apache infront of nginx who acts as a reverse proxy. I was thinking of doing this via nginx/iptables so It wouldn't have to reach apache anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the lua module to block these sorts of users but it is a bit involved.

You can simply ban access to the file by putting the following location block above or within the location block that handles your php :

```
location ~* wp-comments-post\.php {
    return 403;
}
location ~* .+\.php {
    # PHP handling config
}
```

or

```
location ~* .+\.php {
    location ~* wp-comments-post\.php {
        return 403;
    }
    # PHP handling config for others
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using .htaccess file

```
order allow,deny
deny from 192.168.44.201
deny from 224.39.163.12
deny from 172.16.7.92
allow from all
```

or block a range

```
order allow,deny
deny from 192.168.
deny from 10.0.0.
allow from all
```

or even ISP

```
order allow,deny
deny from some-evil-isp.com
deny from subdomain.another-evil-isp.com
allow from all
```

put htaccess file in the directory that contain your file

Comment: Well, I didn't know that :( Are there any better solution?